# declaring variable that calls exact values that is insert into a table

Tags: php, variables

Can anyone show me how to make a variable that calls the exact value inserted into a table?
Because I only know to call from a textbox, like this:

```
$fname = $_POST['txtfirstname'];
$lname = $_POST['txtlastname'];
```

but how would it be if I call the exact inserted value from a table?

```
$fname = ?;
$lname = ?;
```

this would be the code:

```
for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($checkbox);$i++){
$sql2="INSERT INTO tblItems SELECT NULL , '".$checkbox[$i]."' , id FROM tblNames WHERE fname = '".$fname."' AND lname = '".$lname."'";
$result2=mysql_query($sql2);
 }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking how to get a specific value from a database? If so, you need to open a database connection, run a query, and return the result. Which database are you planning on using?

Comment: yes. I already have them. but i just is the value of the variables.

Comment: What database are you using? Have you written a query that returns the value you are looking for? Can you post some more of your code so that we can assist you further?

Comment: i've edited it. I put the codes.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/q0gwD). See the [red box](http://goo.gl/OWwr2)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/orrj0) and use either [PDO](http://goo.gl/TD3xh) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/YXyWL) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/b2ATO). Also see [Why shouldn't I use mysql functions in PHP?](http://goo.gl/J5jAo)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to use the new approach to connect to the database which is called the PDO

here's the manual [PDO MANUAL.](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

To start a new connection you need to use this code.

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=test;host=localhost', $username, $password);
```

To add dynamic fields

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('select name, value from test');
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bindColumn('name', $name);
$stmt->bindColumn('value', $value)
```